# PHP time not showing correct

Tags: php, unix, time

I am getting a result of `Sat 1 Dec 2 pm - 12pm` when I should be getting `Sat 1 Dec,       2pm - 2:45pm` and I am unsure why I am not getting it correct with the times.

```
$startO        = $openHome['Start'];
$finishO        = $openHome['End'];
$startConvert  = preg_replace('~\D~', '', $startO);
$start         = date('D j M g a',$startConvert / 1000);
$finishConvert = preg_replace('~\D~', '', $finishO);
$finish         = date('ga',$finishO / 1000);

$openHomeDetail = $start." - ". $finish;
```

**$startO & $finishO:**

```
"Start":"\/Date(1354323600000)\/","End":"\/Date(1354326300000)\/"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$finish         = date('ga',$finishO / 1000);`

should be:

`$finish         = date('ga',$finishConvert / 1000);`

`$finishO` is an invalid timestamp causing date to see 0 which defaults to unix epoch.